# Error while pushing NuGet-package into GitLab Package Registry -> NuGet.Temporary.Package

Tags: gitlab, nuget

I have trouble with pushing NuGet packages into our company GitLab package registry.

In my NuGet-Package I pack some binaries. Here is the Nuspec-file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>test</id>
    <version></version>
    <authors>Company</authors>
    <description>Demo Project</description>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="../../__out/test/**" target="" />
  </files>
</package>
```

I build the nuget packages which looks good in CI (I have downloaded and inspected the nuget-file)

After the build I push the NuGet-Package with this CI job into the registry.
Gitlab CI:

```yaml
deploy:
  stage: deployNuGet
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim
  script:
    - dotnet nuget add source "$CI_SERVER_URL/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/packages/nuget/index.json" --name gitlab --username gitlab-ci-token --password $CI_JOB_TOKEN --store-password-in-clear-text
    - dotnet nuget push __out/package/test.0.0.1.nupkg" --source gitlab
```

This leads to following CI log:

```bash
$ dotnet nuget add source "$CI_SERVER_URL/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/packages/nuget/index.json" --name gitlab --username gitlab-ci-token --password $CI_JOB_TOKEN --store-password-in-clear-text
Package source with Name: gitlab added successfully.
warn : No API Key was provided and no API Key could be found for 'https://XXXX/api/v4/projects/XXXX/packages/nuget'. To save an API Key for a source use the 'setApiKey' command.
Pushing test.0.0.1.nupkg to 'https://XXXXXX/api/v4/projects/XXXXX/packages/nuget'...
  PUT https://XXXXX/api/v4/projects/XXXXXX/packages/nuget/
  Created https://XXXXX/api/v4/projects/XXXXXX/packages/nuget/ 780ms
Your package was pushed.
```

This worked fine for quit a while, but now I get an different behavior.
The instead of the `test` package there is a `NuGet.Temporary.Package`.

[image]

When I move over the error sign it shows following message:

```
Invalide Package: failed metadate extraction
```

Does someone have an idea how to fix this issu?

Comment: I am having the same problem, as a workaround, building the package with `-c Release` and pushing manually works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since our gitlab was updated it worked fine for me.
If your problem still exists have a look at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/335488#note_623985000

Comment: I'll raise a ticket to our support then, as well.

Comment: Do you know how to delete the registry NuGet.Temporary.Package? The delete button is disabled...

Comment: Try to click on the brocken package.

In the overview page you should have another delete button witch should be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

In the GitLab 16.9 release (which is the latest as of writing) this happens on our self-hosted instance if you either specifiy a `<PackageProjectUrl>` or a `<PackageIconUrl>` inside of your .CSPROJ file.

The "solution"/workaround for .NET (Core) projects is to remove/comment out these properties from the .CSPROJ file.

When building NuGet packages with a separate .NUSPEC file (e.g. for .NET Framework packages), be sure to exclude the `<projectUrl>` node.

See also [my GitLab forum posting](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/335488#note_1788228281).

Answer (score 0):

This was a gitlab (14.0.x) error on self-managed AWS instances.

There is also an MR for fixing this.

Here is the issue with an sulution https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/335488#note_623985000

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of stupid but in case anyone is copy-pasting commands as I was, make sure that you are uploading the correct file (`.nupkg` file). I was uploading the `.csproj` file because I copied and pasted the path from `dotnet pack`. Gitlab does not give a warning or anything if you upload the `.csproj` file.